# Winform use lua to control Mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, lua, logitech-gaming-software

I try to use Logitech mouse to send string like logitech provide a software to do
[image]

I click Forward button it will send string but I can't use winform to send string to it to modify it

I find logitech has [G-series Lua API](https://douile.github.io/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf)

I try to use OnEvent function to control mouse click to send string

But I never Lua before.

Here is my c# code

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LuaInterface;
namespace LuaScript
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Lua lua = new Lua();
        string var = "aabbcc";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lua.DoFile("logitechSendString.lua");
            object[] objs = lua.GetFunction("OnEvent").Call(this, var);
            lua.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My lua code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if (arg!=null)then
    PressKey(arg) 
    ReleaseKey(arg)
    Sleep(50)
    PressMouseButton("Forward")
    ReleaseMouseButton("Forward")
  end
end
```

But it complie error

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
  HResult=0x80131621
  Message=Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
  Source=LuaInterface
  StackTrace: 
   LuaInterface.Lua..ctor()
   LuaScript.Form1..ctor()  D:\Visual Studio\LuaScript\LuaScript\Form1.cs: 15
   LuaScript.Program.Main()  D:\Visual Studio\LuaScript\LuaScript\Program.cs:19
```

How to solve this error?

And How to do use lua to control Mouse?

Thanks

Comment: G-series Lua API is available only for Lua scripts running inside Logitech Gaming Software.  This API is not accessible from external programs (like your C# program).

Comment: To simulate `mouse button #5 X2(Forward)` press and release you don't need Lua at all.  This could be done natively in C#.

Comment: If you just want to simulate typing some message when you're pressing mouse button `Forward` then you need to create a macro in Logitech Gaming Software (press a plus sign next to "Commands" in your picture).  Bind created macro to the mouse button by drag-n-drop the macro name.

Comment: Hi Evor thanks for answering I try to use sg300 because it contain memory it can store string from winform I only need it to store string and send out with click mouse or I can simply simulating cliclking and sending string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution without C#.
The string `aabbcc` is stored in the LGS script.
In your profile's submenu select [Scripting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BrUM.png) and copy this Lua script:

```lua
-- when user presses middle mouse button, the following happens:
--   1. string "aabbcc" typing is simulated
--   2. "Forward" (X2) mouse button press and release simulated
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then  -- middle mouse button pressed
      PressAndReleaseKey("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c")   -- change your string here
      Sleep(50)           -- 50 ms wait
      PressMouseButton(5) -- 5 = X2(Forward)
      Sleep(50)
      ReleaseMouseButton(5)
   end
end
```

To replace string `aabbcc` with another one, you should again go to "Scripting" menu item, modify the text and save it (Ctrl-S).